# Engine Oil Change Leak Seizing?

Tags: oil-change, oil-leak, kia, seizing

Sorry for the long question, it is necessary.

My car is a 2015 Kia Forte Ex (GDI engine 20k miles)

I took my car to get an oil change, tuneup etc. They messed up and it had a major oil leak which became apparent after 5-10 minutes. Had new tires so I was testing them (hard accelerations). Everything seemed fine but I noticed a slight rattle. I know thats not uncommon with GDI engines after an oil change but it sounded different. I ignored it thinking im paranoid.

Then it had a loss of power which I ignored for a short time until on the interstate when I floored it and it didn't even rev past 2k rpms. It felt like more of a transmission issue at that point. Temps were normal, no lights but I thought I smelled something so I pulled over. I come to a stop and THEN the oil light comes on right before turning off the engine. There was oil dripping out (not transmission fluid).

My question is:

I'm going to the repair place where it was towed back to, tomorrow and since I don't trust them obviously, I don't know if I should demand an engine replacement or does it just need oil and the leak fixed? The engine didn't "seize" as in stop running but idk if the loss of power was physical or the computer as there were no warning lights until I stopped. How do I know this is not going to cause engine failure in 5k miles?

Comment: How low was the oil?  Did you check the dipstick, wipe it clean and see if anything was on it when you put it back in?

Comment: @Craig Old post I forgot I made until I got an email about a new comment. The engine was totaled. When it was restarted it sounded like someone shaking nails in a can. 

Firestone admitted the person who changed the oil forgot the drain plug... They tried to use a used engine at around same mileage and swap it for free. Kia got wind of that and called me and set them straight.  The Kia person on the phone was pissed. Was towed  from firestone within an hour. 

Kia put in a brand new engine and made firestone pay for it and the rental car of my choice. I didn't have to do anything more.